# Replacing a value based on scalar condition in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set in pandas Dataframe. For simplicity the data frame may look like something like the following:

```
    a   b   c
k  0.1 1.2 -2.0
j  5   5.7 -.5
h  2.1 2.2 1.2
```

I want to set a condition that if the value is less than 0, I want to set it to 0.

For instance

```
if df.iloc[:,1:]<0:
   df.iloc[:,1:]=0
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Do you have any ideas on how I can fix it?

Or if I want to set a condition that the value is less than 0.5, I want to call it 0. Any way to express this?

Comment: We've already been over this. The solution is to use `df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].clip(lower=0)`

Comment: @cs95 what if I want to call value less than 0.5 to be 0? Would I use df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].clip(lower=0.5)?

Comment: That's a different question from the one presented here. but the answer to that would be `df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.where( df.iloc[:, 1:] < 0.5, 0, df.iloc[:, 1:])` or something similar...

Comment: Well, I edited the question so that that aspect is included..

Comment: Well, you're asking two questions now, but I've reopened it for you. I've already given you your answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will using `mask`

```
df=df.mask(df<0,0)
df
Out[229]: 
     a    b    c
k  0.1  1.2  0.0
j  5.0  5.7  0.0
h  2.1  2.2  1.2
```